# Can't cast embeded MovieClip to MovieClip type

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, movieclip

I'm having trouble trying to embed a MovieClip in an ActionScript file I'm composing in FlashBuilder.

```
    public class ItRock extends Item
    {
        public static const ID:String = "rock";

        [Embed (source="/../art/menu/console.swf", symbol="itRock")] 
        private var IconClass:Class;

        public function ItRock(game:Game)
        {
            super(ID, game);
            var icon = new IconClass();
//          var icon : MovieClip = new IconClass();
//          var icon : MovieClip = new IconClass() as MovieClip;
            addChild(icon);
        }   
    }
```

My console.swf file contains a symbol called itRock which is of type MOvieClip and set to Export for ActionScript.  In my code, I want to create an instance of this symbol and add it as a child of my Item class(which extends Sprite).  However, when I create an instance of the embedded class, I create an object with the type name of console_swf$831ea9c30fe7882fadc388b74e115654-652499362.  I can add it as a child fine, but if I try to cast it to a MovieClip implicitly I get an error that cannot be converted to a MovieClip.  If I try to cast explicitly,  I just get null.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it looks like Flash will automatically convert your MovieClips to Sprites when it can.  So my above code will work if I change the MovieClip classes to Sprite.

The below website describes this.  It suggested that adding an extra frame to your symbol will force Flash to treat is as a MovieClip and not a Sprite - however, I've created a simple two frame animation and its still exported as a Sprite.  (It even plays the animation - I thought Sprites were supposed to be just static images with no animation?)

http://chrismweb.com/2011/03/20/problems-with-embedding-swfs-in-actionscript-or-flex/